# How to use session in MVC3 for login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new at MVC3 and could you tell me and show an example how can I use session for checking user logged or not at different views ?

Comment: you're after something more than " if (Request.IsAuthenticated) "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the asp.net membership you wont need to access the session in order to check the user state.

you can use :

```
Requrest.isAuthenticated //(HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated Property (System.Web))
```

return true if the user is authenticated , false otherwise.

**To access the session**

```
Session["variableName"] = "value";
```

Comment: So how can I check could you explain it more ?